# reverse proxy doesn't work with .svc url?

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, rewrite

here's my attempt to do a reverse proxy using url rewrite in `IIS` from `mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com` to `mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com`

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,RequestRouting" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="400-999" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I call website using `mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com/myApp` it works (render the page/etc). But if I call `mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com/myApp.svc` I got an 404.

Why? Where am I wrong on this configuration?

**EDIT**
Here's the failedRequest tag's attribute:

```
<failedRequest url="http://mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com/myApp.svc"
               siteId="6"
               appPoolId="services"
               processId="2192"
               verb="GET"
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{8000002B-0000-9900-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="404"
               triggerStatusCode="404"
               timeTaken="141"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
```

**EDIT2**

xml opened by browser:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nTEF.png)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi enabled, and edited the answer! That's the first tag I got, but its not so "speaking". Which tag do I need to investigate more?

Comment: EDIT: added the whole web.config, so we can investigate further!

Comment: The article shows so clear how to read FRT log, so I wonder how much of it you have read.

Comment: @LexLi not really. I've read the log, there's nothing "wrong" on it.

Answer (score 0):

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158060/iis7-url-rewrite-returns-404-for-wcf-requests-reverse-proxy) from way back in 2013 suggests you may need to add the `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"` attribute to the `<serviceHostingEnvironment>` tag of your WCF (.svc) service's web.config. Otherwise, WCF will be rejecting your HTTP requests because it does not believe that it is meant to be handling requests for that hostname and path.

Perhaps give that a try?

Comment: Already tried. Nothing changed...

Comment: Would you by chance be able to supply a *full* failed request tracing XML? The line you've provided gives no insights as to where the request lifecycle is failing.

Comment: looks at the image attached. better now?